# How can I add a trigger to check if a value is within a range before inserting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table example :
Table T1(
ID int primary key,

n1 int
)

How can I add a trigger to check if n1 is between 0 and 10 before inserting?

Comment: Use a check constraint, e.g. CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int CHECK (Age>=18)
);

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: Which age? The question has nothing to do with an age, it's not necessary to create other examples instead of just asking the question.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I must say, it's kind of weird to have `Age` in a database, you would normally do `DOB`

Comment: @JonasMetzler Was replying to someone else

Answer (score 0):

Answer by [@500-InternalServerError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72673745/how-can-i-add-a-trigger-to-check-if-a-value-is-within-a-range-before-inserting#comment128370175_72673745) (will delete if they post):

---

There is no need for a trigger. Use a `CHECK` constraint instead.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
  ID int NOT NULL,
  LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar(255),
  Age int CHECK (Age>=18)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=889d04189cdf9a8177fb99b38dca2bc3)

Comment: I'm preparing for my final exam and found this question in last year's exam

Comment: @he8st And therefore...? Adding a trigger is simply not the correct way to do this.

Comment: I know that the optimal way to do this is to add a check constraint to the table, but the the exam's question was to create a trigger